# AttributeOverrides annotation dont create right names of column

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Hello I had a problem with Hibernate and @AttributeOverrides annotation.

I had embedable class money

```
@Embeddable
 public class Money implements Serializable {

     private BigDecimal denomination;

     private String currencyCode;

 }
```

And entity Loan that contains two money object: Value and Interests

```
 @Entity
 public class Loan {

     @AttributeOverrides({
             @AttributeOverride(name = "valuedenomination", column = @Column(name = "valuedenomination")),
             @AttributeOverride(name = "valuecurrencycode", column = @Column(name = "valuecurrencycode")) })
     private Money value;

    @AttributeOverrides({
             @AttributeOverride(name = "interestdenomination", column = @Column(name = "interestdenomination")),
             @AttributeOverride(name = "interestcurrencycode", column = @Column(name = "interestcurrencycode")) })
     private Money interest;

 }
```

When I trying to package application I got follow cause exception:

Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: org.finance.app.core.domain.common.loan.Loan column: currencyCode (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")

When I removed One Money entity from Loam in dataBase I got two fields:
currencyCode and denomination instead of valuecurrencyCode and valuedenomination as I put in AttributeOverrides.

Do I miss something with AttributeOverrides annotation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**AttributeOverride::name**](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/AttributeOverride.html#name%28%29) should be the name of property inside embedded class `Money`. So your mapping should looks like:

```
 @Entity
 public class Loan {

     @AttributeOverrides({
             @AttributeOverride(name = "denomination", 
                                column = @Column(name = "valuedenomination")),
             @AttributeOverride(name = "currencyCode", 
                                column = @Column(name = "valuecurrencycode")) })
     private Money value;

    @AttributeOverrides({
             @AttributeOverride(name = "denomination", 
                                column = @Column(name = "interestdenomination")),
             @AttributeOverride(name = "currencyCode", 
                                column = @Column(name = "interestcurrencycode")) })
     private Money interest;

 }
```